# Can any random vector $\mathbf{y}$ with covariance matrix $\Sigma$ be represented by $\mathbf{\Sigma}^{1/2}\mathbf{x}$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that the components of the $n$-dimensional random vector $\mathbf{x}$ are independent with zero mean and variance $1$, that is,
$$
\mathsf{Cov}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{I}.
$$
Let $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{Ax}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is a positive definite matrix, we know that
$$
\mathsf{Cov}(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{y}) = \mathsf{Cov}(\mathbf{Ax},\mathbf{Ax}) = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\mathsf{T}}:=\Sigma. 
$$

I wonder if the reverse holds or not. That is, if we know $\mathsf{Cov}(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{y})=\Sigma$, does there exist matrix $\mathbf{A}$ satisfying $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{\mathsf{T}}=\Sigma$ such that
$$
\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{Ax},
$$
where $\mathsf{Cov}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{I}$.

It is true if $\mathbf{y}$ follows a multivariate normal distribution. What about other distributions?

Answer (score 1):

For every symmetric positive-definite matrix $\Sigma$ (this is always satisfied for a  covariance matrix) there is a decomposition of the form $\Sigma=GG^T$. It is called the Cholesky decomposition. Then you have to solve the linear system
$$y=Gx.$$
But I think your solution $x$ might be not a random vector with independent components in general.

Comment: Denote $\mathbf{A}=\Sigma^{1/2}$ and let $\Sigma^{-1/2}$ be the inverse of $\Sigma^{1/2}$. We have $\mathbf{x}=\Sigma^{-1/2}\mathbf{y}$ and $$\mathsf{Cov}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x})=\mathsf{Cov}(\Sigma^{-1/2}\mathbf{y},\Sigma^{-1/2}\mathbf{y})=\Sigma^{-1/2}\cdot \Sigma\cdot \Sigma^{-1/2}=\mathbf{I},$$ does it mean the component of $\mathbf{x}$ are independent?

Comment: This means the components are uncorrelated, but in general not independent. You need further assumptions to conclude from uncorrelatedness to [independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncorrelatedness_(probability_theory)#When_uncorrelatedness_implies_independence).